# Program not breaking for some reason, counts the # of characters in "quit" instead of breaking

Tags: java, break

This program is meant to take the users input and tell them how many of each vowel there is. When "quit" is entered, the program does not break but instead just counts "quits" characters. Any ideas why? I have tried multiple ways of rephrasing the while statement but nothings seems to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      String phrase = "";    // a string of characters
  int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
  int length;       // the length of the phrase
  char ch;          // an individual character in the string
  int countA, countE, countI, countO, countU ;


  // Print a program header
  System.out.println ();
  System.out.println ("Character Counter");
  System.out.println ();

  // Read in a string and find its length



  // a for loop to go through the string character by character
  // and count the blank spaces
  while(!phrase.equals("quit")){
      length = phrase.length();


             Scanner imp = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
             phrase = imp.nextLine();
             //put to lowercase in order to take uppercase ch's
             phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();

             if(phrase == "quit"){
          break;
        }
      // set things equal to zero before starting count
      countA = 0;
      countE = 0;
      countI = 0;
      countO = 0;
      countU = 0;
      countBlank = 0;


      //for loop to count
      for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length();i++){
          if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' '){
              countBlank++;

            }
          if(phrase.charAt(i) == 'a'){
              countA++;

            }
          if(phrase.charAt(i) == 'e'){
              countE++;

            }
          if(phrase.charAt(i) == 'i'){
              countI++;

            }
          if(phrase.charAt(i) == 'o'){
              countO++;

            }
          if(phrase.charAt(i) == 'u'){
              countU++;
            }

    }

  // Print the results
  System.out.println ();
  System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
  System.out.println ();
  System.out.println("Number of a's: " + countA);
  System.out.println("Number of e's: " + countE);
  System.out.println("Number of i's: " + countI);
  System.out.println("Number of o's: " + countO);
  System.out.println("Number of u's: " + countU);

}
}
}
```

Comment: you have to just change one line, i.e. if(phrase.equals("quit")){break;} it will work what you expect...!! cheers

Comment: thanks so much brother